# Static classes in web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static

Is it a bad choice to use static classes in web applications?

Lets say one is using a static class for role validation, if user is in role x. Im thinking that it might queue up to use the class when there is a lot of users.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What would queue up? As far as I know, multiple threads can access a static class or method *at the same time*, realizing that nothing actually happens at the same time on a CPU. Have you tried both instantiated and static approaches? What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps most importantly, why not just use or extend the built-in role provider?

Answer (score 3):

Static classes are just fine within a web application. Just remember that all threads are able to access that class at the same time, so you need to consider the thread-safety of your operations. In your example, role validation, that would be quite reasonable because you could load the roles when the application starts and *just read from that* during execution. That would make your class thread-safe.

I use a static class to cache information like the user id based off of user name in an MVC application. Now, when dealing with caching you need to worry about thread-safety because you are both reading and writing at times. But you get the picture. Static information in a web application is 100% okay.

Comment: +1 for thread-safety which is, I think, the only actual problem that could arise from using static vs. non-static classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a shared resource in that static class or something,and locking implemented to make it thread-safe - you wont have any queue up problem while accessing it at the same time from multiple users/requests/threads.