# Static class storing current user in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, static-classes

I'm new to web application in asp.net mvc 5. I'm curious about how static classes behaves in web application. I'd like to know how my program will behave.

Let's say I have CurrentUser static class which stores logged user id.

```
public static class CurrentUser{
     public static int UserId {get; set;}
}
```

Which is set whenerever user is logging in. 
My app is in external server.

So what will happen if:

1. User A log in -> userId is set to 1, then User B log in (they access to from differentlcoations) so user Id is set to 2. When User A would like to perform action which need to check his Id, will it be 1 or 2?
2. I checked one scenario where 2 differentpersons log in from one pc at the same time (different tabs) and I know that User Id will be 2 for both of them (when User B logged in as second to the app). How to resolve this?

I've already read: [Static classes in web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363410/static-classes-in-web-applications).
I know that my solution may be error prone because every one has access to that class but I don't know if static classes in web app aren't store per user (thread?)?

Answer (score 0):

If you store current user in session storage it will be better than static class. Because there is one copy of static class and fields and for every user login the last login is kept.